# Uniqueness of the trajectories of the solution of an SDE

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider an SDE
\begin{equation}
dX_t=f(X_t,t)dt+b(X_t,t)dW_t
\end{equation}
Suppose firstly that the coefficient are Lipschitz continuous. So by the theorem of existence and unicity I have that exist a strong solution and this is unique. So, can I say, that fixed an $\omega$ two trajectory can't intersect each other?

If the coefficient of the diffusion term isn't Lipschitz,(like $\sqrt{...})$, and a unique solution exist can be that the two trajectories intersect?

Comment: If $f(X_{t},t)=0$ and $b(X_{t},t)=1$ then the solution is of the form $X_{t}=W_{t}$. Now, consider two trajectories $W_{t}(\omega_{1})$ and $W_{t}(\omega_{2})$. Can or cannot intersect each other?

Comment: @Leon Yes, I think that can intersect each other...So, what is the meaning of pathwise uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

From Shreve-Karatzas notes chapter 5, we have the global Lipschitz implies strong uniqueness i.e.

$$P[X_{t}=Y_{t};0\leq t<\infty]=1.$$

So yes for almost every $\omega$ we have $X_{t}(\omega)=Y_{t}(\omega)$ for all $t\geq 0$.

In dimension one, Yamada-Watanabe (prop 2.13) gives strong uniqueness for the volatility coefficients whose modulus satisfies a singular-integral-condition $\int_{0}^{\epsilon} 1/\omega^{2}(s)ds=+\infty,\forall \epsilon>0$ (this includes $|x|^{a}$ for $a\geq 1/2$).

If we don't even have the Yamada-Watanabe-setting, then we can lose uniqueness. In 3.5 example, the $dX_{t}=sgn(X_{t})dW_{t}$ has a weak solution and uniqueness in law i.e.

$$(X)_{t\geq 0}\stackrel{d}{=}(Y)_{t\geq 0}$$

but it does not have pathwise uniqueness because by Dubins-Schwarz both $X=Brownian~motion$ and $Y=-X$ are solutions yet they are not equal as paths.